# Track CreatedBy and UpdatedBy in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cmodel

I have the database like this

```
=== Group ===
id
member_id
decsription

=== Member ===
id
name
description
```

Everything is working fine.Now I extended my Group table and added some extra field like `created_by` and `updated_by`,by which I can track who has created and who has made the changes.So to achieve what should I do and how to do that?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend beforeSave / beforeUpdate in your AR class and simply set $this->updated_by = Yii::app()->user->getId(); on update. If you override these methods, make sure to return true when you are done so that you do not prevent save. You can also set created_at and updated_at to new CDbExpression('NOW()'); so that these are always up to date as well.

Hope this helps!

Note: Not saying it's very nice to have your AR models know about the currently signed in user, but it should work just fine and it's worth considering.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using timestamps in the db instead of datetime, due to timezone issues.

also, by putting Yii::app()->user->id in your models, you have to be careful about unit testing and command line usage. Make sure to set Yii::app()->user->id to something useful in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

If its a web application , then you can use the session to put the user info into the session and access the user id and persist that in the database ( make sure that you have foreign key to the user table )

If you are using Spring framework , you can look at using interceptors to access and set the user id for every database update call

Comment: No Spring: this is a PHP web app if you look at the tags (yii framework, php, mysql)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your `created_by` and `updated_by` fields are DATETIME then when you run `UPDATE` queries against them to update the data, make sure you pass `NOW()` without any quotes. This will update those fields to the current `DATETIME` e.g. `2012-02-17 10:00:00`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not created_**on**, it's created_**by**.

Comment: Ok thanks @arkin for such quick reply.I want to know how to get the creator id and the person who has made updated his id in that field.